# WinInet receive response

Tags: java, delphi, wininet

I have this server(java):

```
ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(8080);
Socket accept = s.accept();
InputStream inputStream = accept.getInputStream();
while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
    char b = (char) inputStream.read();
    System.out.print(b);
}
System.out.println("finish recieve");

System.out.println("start write");
OutputStream outputStream = accept.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n asdf".getBytes());
System.out.println("data sent to client");
outputStream.flush();
accept.close();
```

And this client (delphi):

```
if not InternetWriteFile(hRequest, pchar(json.DelimitedText), length(json.DelimitedText), count) then
  showmessage('Send content problem: ' + inttostr(getlasterror));

showmessage('Wait for server to send data');

if not InternetGetLastResponseInfo(statusCode, resp, read) then
  showmessage('Error '+IntToStr(GetLastError));
showmessage('response-size:' + inttostr(read));
if not HttpEndRequest(hRequest,nil,0,0) then
  showmessage('Send end problem: ' + inttostr(getlasterror));
InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);
InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
InternetCloseHandle(hConn);
```

I run the server, than the client.

The client finally shows me the dialog `Wait for server to send data`.

I check the Java-Server and the last lines are

```
start write
data sent to client
```

Ok, I assuming the client recieved data in an internal buffer. I press the dialog away but the next dialog is `response-size:0`.

How to recieve the `hello` in the client?

Comment: The server does not use HTTP it just reads a byte stream and so HttpEndRequest can not be used. The server also has some issues: the resources are never closed, and no specific encoding is used.

Comment: WinInet is not a very good choice for TCP client implementation (if it's possible at all). You should use Winsock if you like low-level things or Indy (TIdTCPClient) library if you just want to make it work.

Comment: @mjn Yes, I never send a `200 OK` from the server to the client. Ill check this. I currently do not care about resource close. What do you mean with encoding?

Comment: @mjn Sent the 200 OK